# Deep Copy of XML files in a list

Tags: c#, xml, list, unity-game-engine, deep-copy

I'm not sure how to go about doing a deep copy of a XML file that is stored in a list. I had read up on some of the post here, Some uses Serialize & some uses Icloneable. which method is the best?

Currently I had only read the XML files and store it in a list.

```
TextAsset XMLFile;
public GameObject spawnAlert;

List<AlertInfo> m_AlertInfo = new List<AlertInfo>();

public class AlertInfo
{
    public string strId     { get; set; }
    public string strName   { get; set; }
    public Vector3 vectSpawnPos = new Vector3();
}

void Start()
{
    TextAsset textXML = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("Alert", typeof(TextAsset));
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(textXML.text);


    XmlNode root = xml.FirstChild;

    for( int x = 0; x < root.ChildNodes.Count; x++)
    {
        AlertInfo alertI = new AlertInfo();

        alertI.strId = root.ChildNodes[x].Attributes[0].Value;
        alertI.strName = root.ChildNodes[x].Attributes[1].Value;

        alertI.vectSpawnPos.x = float.Parse( root.ChildNodes[x].Attributes[2].Value);
        alertI.vectSpawnPos.y = float.Parse( root.ChildNodes[x].Attributes[3].Value);
        alertI.vectSpawnPos.z = float.Parse( root.ChildNodes[x].Attributes[4].Value);

        m_AlertInfo.Add( alertI );
    }

<ListOfAlerts>
    <AlertInfo id = "1"     Name = "Unsecured Aircraft"                                     pos_X = "0" pos_Y = "0" pos_Z = "0" />
    <AlertInfo id = "2"     Name = "Suspecious Baggage Found at Lobby"                          pos_X = "0" pos_Y = "0" pos_Z = "0" />
    <AlertInfo id = "3"     Name = "Disruptive person at Departure Hall"                                pos_X = "0" pos_Y = "0" pos_Z = "0" />
    <AlertInfo id = "4"     Name = "Suspicious person loitering around at Arrival Hall"             pos_X = "0"pos_Y = "0"  pos_Z = "0" />
</ListOfAlerts>
```

Comment: If it is a resource, why deep copying it anyway? Why not loading it twice?

Comment: oh! I wanted to deep copy the list and loop through the copied list to randomly retrieve a alert based on the id and display. after which the alert that has been displayed will be remove. So in future i can update the original list with more alerts.

Comment: can you provide your xml content ? maybe little piece for sample then we can see element and attribute names ?

Comment: I have updated the XML content in it. The pos_x,y,z is for where i want the alert message to pop up in my unity. But currently set to 0 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `LINQ to XML` ?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("textXML.text");

var myList = xDoc.Descendants("AlertInfo").Select(x => new AlertInfo()
        {
            strId = (string) x.Attribute("id"),
            strName = (string) x.Attribute("Name"),
            vectSpawnPos = new Vector3
            {
                x = (float) x.Attribute("pos_X"),
                y = (float) x.Attribute("pos_Y"),
                z = (float) x.Attribute("pos_Z")
            }
        }).ToList();
```

To use this code you need to make a little change.Make your `vectSpawnPos` auto-implemented property like:

```
public Vector3 vectSpawnPos { get; set; }
```

And your `Vector3` class should look like:

```
public class Vector3
{
    public float x { get; set; }

    public float y { get; set; }

    public float z { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried putting get; set; for the vectspawnpos but it returns me a null exception. But if i use new vector3 it says text node cannot appear in this state. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: @user3128861 You should make Vector3 class public